# Abstract class without any inheritance

Tags: python, abstract-class

Basically, I know that abstract base classes are used as skeleton classes just like regular classes, and there main advantage would be to enforce their implementation on the child classes.

But I was wondering if I have the next case:

I have a class which is having **only static methods** / **no init** -> **it would make sense to make it abstract?** It would be pythonic?

I was thinking the advantage would be that some one reading the code would know that that class should not be instantiated...

Comment: No, in that case it's better to use a module. People's opinions may vary though.

Comment: Are you referring to the abstract base class mechanics from the `abc` module, or some more general sort of abstractness (like a method that returns `NotImplemented` or raises an exception)?

Comment: Classes which are never instantiated shouldn't be classes to begin with.

Comment: @Blckknght I refer to the first variant from the abc module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to emulate namespaces. It's better to use modules. The mechanism is built into Python, and functions as a namespace:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

An abstract class with only static-methods can work as a namespace, but it's confusing to people reading the source code

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class which is having only static methods / no init -> it
> would make sense to make it abstract? It would be pythonic?

[PEP 3119](https://peps.python.org/pep-3119/) gives following rationale for Abstract Base Class

> This PEP proposes a particular strategy for organizing these tests
> known as Abstract Base Classes, or ABC. ABCs are simply Python classes
> that are added into an object’s inheritance tree to signal certain
> features of that object to an external inspector. Tests are done using
> `isinstance()`, and the presence of a particular ABC means that the test
> has passed.

Taking this in account I would find it confusing to find Abstract Base Class which is then not inherited at all. If all methods are static why do not simply make all of them just functions?

Comment: To be honest they, all 5 methods are doing similar jobs( they generate some automatic license.txt files based on config.json file ( with the tools .exe files paths ), I wanted them to incapsulate them all inside a class.. I was thinking is making more sense taking in consideration they are all doing similar stuff in order to provide a output..